# google spreadsheet using conditional formating based on another cells value

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, background-color

I'm using Google spreadsheet and working on a daily dashboard. What I need is to change the background color of a row of cells A15:W15 based on the value of another cell - J14="Finished". I've seen and practived single cells and columns but an entire row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answer:

[here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2F1ScDqtZvhsmf2iByAuxHBu0-ESpX_TE5pdtBvAxOJ99E%2Fedit%3Fusp%3Dsharing&ei=cGcdVfrmKMayoQTz14GgCQ&usg=AFQjCNHxSpA39LvLyEvvEfVgWkJAkkf9AA&sig2=cpzXr6w7PHL69yM1hgcbIw)

Sheet Test4 is what you want.

Change the "Apply to range" to A15:W15 and Format Cells if...Custom Formula is

=$J$14="Finished"

Test2 and Test3 show how to select entire row if you want more than A15:W15.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go and let you know how I do.